# Standard tiles with data binding

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5, tiles

I am new to SAPUI5 development and tried to create a page with standard tiles inside a tile container. I created a data.json file which contains the following information:

```
{
  "TileCollection" : [
    {
      "icon" : "edit",
      "type" : "Monitor",
      "press":  "onEditClick",
      "title" : "Global MasterData Characteristics Maintenance Tool"
    }, 
    {
      "icon" : "activity-assigned-to-goal",
      "type" : "Monitor",
      "press":  "onAssignClick",
      "title" : "Global MasterData Characteristics Assignment Tool"
    },     
    {
      "icon" : "map",
      "type" : "Monitor",
      "press":  "onMappingClick",      
      "title" : "Global MasterData Characteristics Mapping Tool"
    }    
  ]
}
```

inside my xml view I then use the code below, when I replace the below dynamic entry from {press} to e.g. onEditClick then the event works but with the dynamic content nothing happens when I Click the tile. I hope anyone can help in the right direction?

```
<TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
                <StandardTile 
                    icon = "sap-icon://{icon}"      
                    type = "Monitor"
                    press = "{press}"
                    title = "{title}" />
            </TileContainer>
```

Just to be sure, the icon and title are loaded correctly in runtime so the JSON file is loaded and used, only the press property does not seem to be applied.

Kind Regards, 
Nico van der Linden

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nico van der Linden,

U need to change the binding for the press event.

the code should be something like this:

```
<TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
            <StandardTile 
                icon = "sap-icon://{icon}"      
                type = "Monitor"
                press = "FunctionPress"
                title = "{title}" />
        </TileContainer>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks  for your reaction. If I do it that way it indeed works, but then all tiles launch the same method. Which will be ok if there is a way to retrieve the id or something of the clicked tile? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it :-) Indeed it seems that you cannot bind the press event itself. So what I now did was create an parameter id-tile in the json file which has the value of the views that are part of the application. So the JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "TileCollection" : [
    {
      "id-tile": "maintenance",
      "icon" : "edit",
      "type" : "Monitor",
      "info" : "Central",
      "title" : "Global MDM"
    }, 
    {
      "id-tile": "assignment",
      "icon" : "activity-assigned-to-goal",
      "type" : "Monitor",
      "info" : "Local",
      "title" : "Product and Customer Mapping "
    }
}
```

Then in the view I use a standard tile as follows:

```
> <StandardTile
>               icon="sap-icon://{tiles>icon}"
>               type="{tiles>type}"
>               number="{tiles>number}"
>               numberUnit="{tiles>numberUnit}"
>               press="handleTilepress"
>               title="{tiles>title}"
>               info="{tiles>info}"
>               infoState="{tiles>infoState}" />
```

So this means that each tile on the page launches the same event in the controller file. So finally in the controller I use the "id-tile" from the bindingContext to see on which tile was clicked and the value of the parameter is then assigned to the "navTo" command to do the actual routing.

```
handleTilepress: function(oEvent) {
            var selectedPage = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("tiles").getProperty("id-tile");
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.navTo(selectedPage);
}
```

Thank you all for the reply's! I am very new to SAPUI5 development and I don't know if this is the best way of doing it but it seems to work fine for me :-)

Regards, 
Nico